# Update $key of Firebase object using AngularFire2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to update only the $key of an object from my Firebase database. All the values in the object I want to keep untouched.
I tried this way:

```
this.af.object('personalMessages/'+ firebase_uid).update({ $key: 'my custom key' })
```

I get no error, but the record is not updating.

The big objects looks like this:

```
personalMessages:{
     the_key_I_want_to_update:
    {
         isRead:  false
         text: "some text goes here"
         timestamp:   1502448955231.222

    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is no way to update the key. You need to retrieve the value in a key, then store value in a new key and remove old key.

Comment: It's seems that the only solution is to remove the old key and create a new one with the new name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107274/is-it-possible-to-rename-a-key-in-the-firebase-realtime-database

Comment: This was, also, the soution I've implemented, but it causes other bugs. Thank you, anyways, for the response! :)