# Firebase - Join chat with password securely

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

How to check if user enters correct password to join a chat.

This approach is propably compeletely improper. This piece of code is just to show what I want to accomplish but it isn't working at all.

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chats")  

ref.child(chatName).child("password").equalTo(password).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(   
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, snapshot.toString())
        // if there is data the password was right
    }
    ....
)
```

How can this whole join chat with password system be done securely? What kind of rules do I have to set to the database.

Is it possible to alter firebase queries with rooted phone and see the data that is transferred between client and the server?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to secure each chat room with a password, one option is to embed that password into the path of the chat room. So for example:

```
chats: {
  roomId1: {
    secret: {
      chat11: ...
      chat12: ...
    }
  }
  roomId2: {
    correcthorsebatterystaple: {
      chat21: ...
      chat22: ...
    }
  }
```

Secure this structure with the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "chats": {
      "$roomId": {
        "$password: {
          ".read": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this structure, nobody can read the list of rooms, or even a specific room. To be able to read they must *know* both the room Id and the password for that room.

Comment: How the password can be changed?

Comment: With this model you will have to move all the messages if you want to change the password. Since there is no operation to rename/move a branch, this will require that you copy then. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107274/is-it-possible-to-rename-a-key-in-the-firebase-realtime-database

Comment: Then I am still searching for another way to do this. Thanks although.